# css style to set minimum width of div else according to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can i set minimum width  for div . My problem is i am dynamically loading content in a div some time it is large and some time it is small.

if it is small then behind div becomes invisible so i want to avoid that . and set div to minimum equal to parent div height or if content is more than auto ??

CSS::

```
#middle_overlay
{

position:absolute;
/*border:2px solid #008080;
background-color:#CCCCCC;*/
background-image:url(../images/bg2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
height:auto;
width:100%;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: "and set div to minimum equal to parent div height" DIV width or height??? I don't get it

Answer (score 2):

Would `min-width:xxx;` work for you?

> The min-width CSS property is used to set the minimum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the used value of the width property from
>   becoming smaller than the value specified for min-width.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) for further information

Comment: Agree. Just don't forget to use either `px` or `em` together with the size.

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` - This prevents the value of the width property from becoming smaller than min-width. `min-width:450px;`   or `min-width:50em;`

```
#middle_overlay
{
position:absolute;
/*border:2px solid #008080;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;*/
background-image:url(../images/bg2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
height:auto;
width:100%;
display:none;
min-width:450px; //50em 
}
```

**Note:** The value of the min-width property overrides both max-width and width.